# How to get .hover to work with if statement

Tags: jquery, if-statement, jquery-hover, mousehover

I have a page with tabs (each tab labeled as column 1, 2, and 4). Trying to figure out how to get the .hover function to work and make said tab -> $('.column1').css("left", "calc(-100vw + 180px)"); grow to 190px when you hover over...? but only when the tab is in its "calc(-100vw + 180px)" state not $(".column1").css("left", "0"); which is when it is completely open.

```
$(".column1").on("click", function(){
    if ($('.column1').hasClass("closed")){
    $(".column1").css("left", "0");
    }
    else {
    $(".column1").css("left", "0");
    $(".column2").css("left", "0");
    $(".column4").css("left", "0");
    }

});

$(".column2").on("click", function(){
    if ($('.column2').hasClass("closed")){
        $(".column2").css("left", "0");
    }
    else {
        $(".column2").css("left", "0");
        $('.column1').css("left", "calc(-100vw + 180px)");
        $(".column4").css("left", "0");
    }

});


$(".column4").on("click", function(){
    if ($('.column4').hasClass("closed")){
        $(".column4").css("left", "0");
    }
    else {
        $('.column1').css("left", "calc(-100vw + 180px)");
        $('.column2').css("left", "calc(-100vw + 190px)");
        $(".column2").hasClass("closed");
        $(".column1").hasClass("closed");
    }    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To change a property while the mouse is positioned over the object it would be better to use the "mouseover" event to add the effect you want to have when the mouse is over the element.
And the "mouseleave" event to remove the effect.

```
$(".column1,.column2,.column4").on("mouseover", function(){
    $(this).css("left", "doWhatYouWantWhenMouseIsOnTheElement()");
});

$(".column1,.column2,.column4").on("mouseleave", function(){
    $(this).css("left", "revertWhatYouHaveDoneInTheOv()");
});
```

Comment: used what you suggested, but then when hovering over column 1 and 2 automatically close and overrides .on "click"